# Graphics Card Dead out of box?

Tags: motherboard, graphics

So I'm building a new (Budget) PC to hackintosh, and I get the parts and plug it all in (PSU, RAM, GPU) and the monitor reads "No Input Signal" from both the VGA port and the DVI port. So I think "Ok it's a bad Graphics Card" and to check that I plug it into my old PC, power it on and "No Input Signal" is on the monitor again, then I move the VGA cable from the monitor to the integrated port on the motherboard and it boots up properly into the login page etc...

So this graphics card is a PCI-Express card with no extra power needed it has a small fan and a heat sink the fan works but not the video out adapters? This was new from Amazon, had to cut that plastic wrap off the box too. I can't imagine that it doesn't work?

Here's my build:
MOBO- GA-EP43-UD3L (used from EBay, seller had 100% positive reviews, this    motherboard will do 1 long and 2 short post beeps when I power it on    ( The power button doesn't work right either, you have to push it    down then let it pop back up but not so much that it clicks, but    enough that it's not all the way down, then sometimes it works and it    will shut off and sometimes you have to kinda wiggle it around and    twist it and sometimes you can't shut it off) anyway I looked up what    the gigabyte post beep codes were and the Long, Short, Short meant    that there was a "Graphics Card Error" So I am returning that    graphics card and getting a replacement, shoutout to Amazon! Also it    will beep every 17 seconds LIKE CLOCKWORK! I have timed it and it    will do it EXACTLY every 17 seconds within like 1/10 of a second (my    reaction time) so I'm not sure if the bios is resetting so I need a    new CMOS battery or what?

CPU- Intel Core 2 Duo E8400

RAM- 8GB DDR2 (2x4GB)

HDD- 1 TB SATA

CASE- Logisys CS368RB w/ 480W PSU

Any help is hugely appreciated! As this is my first build and I am in the dark here :/

Comment: It happens. Return it for a refund or replacement

Comment: Refer to the motherboard manual and see what the beep codes mean.